# Multiple one-sample comparisons with random effects against a mu value

Tags: r

I have data with fish treated two separate ways, but each of the treatment types consists of fish from three separate tanks (treatment 1: 30 fish from tanks 1, 2, and 3; treatment 2: 30 fish from tanks 4, 5, and 6). I'm treating tanks as random effects, since I really only care about the effects of the treatments. I've created a model as follows:
`mod=lmer(index~treatment+(1|tank),data=data)`

I would like to conduct a hypothesis test where I compare 1) both treatment groups against the value 0 (i.e. mu=0 for a t.test), 2) both treatment types against each other (i.e. something like t.test(treatment1,treatment2)). Can anyone suggest some tips for how to go about this?